# disabling second text field after data validation through ajax of first text field

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

As I was experimenting with JSF 2.0 , i came across a scenario like this .

I have two text fields - based on input of first field an ajax call is fired using

```
<f:ajax ... />
```

After the response is back I am re rendering the second text field ..but i want to disable the second text field based on some server side validation of first field value.

I don't want to  set the disabled using style based on a third property which is being set in the bean after validation.

Is there any alternative ways..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind the first input component to the view by `binding` attribute and use [`UIInput#isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#isValid%28%29) in the `disabled` attribute of the second input field. It will return `false` if validation has failed on the given input component.

```
<h:inputText binding="#{input1}" value="#{bean.input1}">
    <f:validator validatorId="yourValidator" />
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="input2" />
</h:inputText>
<h:inputText id="input2" value="#{bean.input2}" disabled="#{!input1.valid}" />
```